# Prove the monotonicity of sequence $a_n = {(n+10)!\over 10^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to prove whether $a_n = {(n+10)!\over 10^n}$ is monotonic. I should probably check if $a_n < a_{n+1}$, but I am having trouble simplyfing the expression to get the proof.

$${(n+10)!\over 10^n} < {(n+11)!\over 10^{n+1}}$$

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate your inequality as follows. Since $(n+11)! = (n+11)(n+10)!$ you can write
$$\frac{(n+10)!}{10^n} < \frac{(n+11)!}{10^{n+1}} = \frac{(n+11)(n+10)!}{10^n10},$$
and rearranging the terms you find
$$\frac{(n+10)!}{10^n}\left(\frac{n+11}{10}-1\right) = \frac{(n+10)!}{10^n}\left(\frac{n+1}{10}\right)> 0.$$
Can you conclude from here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider, rather than $a_{n}<a_{n+1}$, wether $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$ (actually they are more or less the same inequality, it just evokes a different frame of mind). There is a *lot* of simplification that can be done to that fraction, and once you have done all the simplifications you can do, it's rather straight-forward to conclude.